# Only run GitHub actions if pr target is master

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to figure out a way how to run GitHub workflow only when pr is opened into master i.e. changes are going into master.

So far I got to this point

```
workflow "Install Yarn Dependencies" {
  on = "pull_request"
  resolves = ["Install"]
}

action "Is Master Branch" {
  uses = "actions/bin/filter@master"
  args = "branch master"
}

action "Install" {
  needs = "Is Master Branch"
  uses = "nuxt/actions-yarn@master"
  args = "install"
}
```

When I open pull request merging `development` branch into `master` branch my `Install` action is not ran, because `Is Master Branch` returns

> refs/heads/development does not match refs/heads/master

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new  `YAML` syntax, you can achieve this like so:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - master
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using [ref](https://github.com/actions/bin/tree/master/filter#ref) instead of `branch`? (I haven't tested this code though)

```
action "Is Master Branch" {
  uses = "actions/bin/filter@master"
  args = "ref refs/heads/master"
}
```